# Do we use Sunday's or Sundays

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms

Which sentence is correct?

> If only all Sunday's were so smooth.

vs

> If only all Sundays were so smooth

Answer (score 5):

Sunday's is ***possessive*** in nature when you use the apostrophe. Use Sundays instead, unless you know someone named Sunday. See the difference below:

> If only all Sundays were so smooth.
>
> If only all Sunday's weather was so smooth.